# Vuejs function with multiple data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two data table in vue app.

- Cash [code, description,cash]
- Upload [bank, id]

For my update function, i need to take [bank, id] from upload and [cash] from cash. i don't know how, can someone help please ? Thank you. This is my code

This is my vuejs

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        cash: {
            codeentry: '',
            description: '',
            cash: '',
        },
        upload: {
            bank: '',
            id: '',
        },
    },
    methods: {
        updateBank: function () {
            axios.put('/updatebank', this.upload, this.cash)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.etat) {
                        this.upload.id = response.data.etat.id
                        this.upload.bank = response.data.etat.bank
                        this.cash.cash = response.data.etat.cash

                    }

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('errors: ', error)
                })
        },
    }
});
```

My route :

```
Route::put('/updatebank', 'CoinController@updateBank');
```

Controller :

```
public function updateBank(Request $request)
{
    $coin = Coin::findOrFail($request->id);
    $coin->bank = ($request->bank - $request->cash);
    $coin->save();
}
```

When i execute my function and see the report. Only this.upload is token in consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to have the two data in one object, you can make a new object from the two objects

Es6 Example:

```
            const {bank,id} = this.upload;
            const {cash} = this.cash;
            const my_data = {
                bank, id, cash
            }
```

Older Js example

```
            var my_data = {
                cash: this.cash.cash,
                bank: this.upload.bank,
                id: this.upload.id,
            }
```

Otherwise, if you want to have both in the request as separate objects then wrap around them `{}`

```
            var my_data = {
                upload: this.upload,
                cash: this.cash
            }
```

Finally:

```
            axios.put('/updatebank', my_data)
                ...
```

**Update**: It appears you don't want to merge those objects as different sub-object so your `updateBank` method would be like so:

```
    updateBank: function () {
        const my_data = {
            cash: this.cash.cash,
            bank: this.upload.bank,
            id: this.upload.id,
        };

        axios.put('/updatebank', my_data)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.upload.id = response.data.etat.id
                    this.upload.bank = response.data.etat.bank
                    this.cash.cash = response.data.etat.cash

                }

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            });
    }
```

> Just a side observation, are you sure the `this` in the response references your Vue object?

Comment: Hello Sir, where do i need to place my var my_data ? Out side my  var app = new Vue ?

Comment: if you declare it outside the Vue context, "this.cash" and "this.upload" will be out of scope

Comment: @monkjuice yes.. so please where do i need to place my var my_data ?

Comment: you can declare a local variable inside your `updateBank()` function like this,

`let  my_data = { upload: this.upload, cash: this.cash }`

Comment: Thanks sir ! but now i have both objects. but i have a error : No query results for model [App\Coin]."

Comment: @yassinej I will update my answer to reflect what you are saying.

Comment: @yassinej I am glad it works. But you could easily track the issue by inspecting what the request contains with `dd($request->all())`. For example, using `{ upload: this.upload, cash: this.cash }` sends a request with both keys as `upload` and `cash` so that they are like an array of this form `["cash" => ['...'], 'upload' => [...]]` but It's easier to use the updated answer so you don't have an array-of-array as request values.

Comment: Okey ! Thank you sir !

Comment: One last question, do you know how can i return upload.id and upload.bank from an existing html table value ligne  with out needed to input them in the form ?